# VSTO - Add controls to worksheet taking much time

Tags: excel, performance, vsto, controls, worksheet

I'm building an excel application using VSTO (VB.NET programming). I need to add comboboxes to the worksheet at the run time, but this operation is taking too long. I'm adding something about 100~500 combos.

I'm doing something like this

```
For Each cell_address In my_cells_address_list
    Dim rng = Me.sheet.Range(cell_address)
    Me.sheet.Controls.AddControl(New ComboBox(), rng, "MyApp_Combo_" & rng.Address(0, 0))
Next
```

To make it faster, I'm doing this (below) before adding the comboboxes

```
Me.sheet.Application.Calculation = Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual
Me.sheet.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Me.sheet.Application.EnableEvents = False
```

But this commands are not improving my performance. I think it's relevant to say that when the combos are added, the sheet is protected and the user can not trigger any basic function of excel.

With the combos, the performance of scrolling the worksheet is very low too...

There is some workaround to make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to add so much combo boxes to the worksheet? Most probably there is more elegant solution to the problem. Have you considered creating a task pane with .Net controls instead?

Also I'd suggest releasing all underlying COM objects instantly. Use System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject to release an Excel object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article. It is related to Outlook, but the same principles can be applied to any Office add-in.